# Referenced Excel cell format not adjusting

Tags: excel, text, formula

Trying to get a text() result in a certain format "MM/YY", the referenced cell datatype doesn't seems to change no matter the character ("Number") Format.

w/ Ctrl `

[image]

after

[image]

Tried adjusting the "Number" category to "General" and basically ever trick up my shelve.

Excel Options are on Auto.

Could this be a REG issue?

Using Pro Plus 2010.

Please help.

Comment: The problem is the entries on the left (column Z it looks like) that aren't formatting are *text that look like dates* and not actually date values.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the TEXT() function is text, not a number, therefore number formatting will have no effect.

If you want to use number formatting, just create a reference to the cell

`=Z227`

then format the cell with the desired number format.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest you use =datevalue(A1) to convert your text to excel serial date, but it kept giving me an error for some reason.  so instead I put together this bit of formula that rips the text out and converts it to a datevalue another way

```
 =TEXT(IF(ISTEXT(A1),DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2)),A1),"MM/YY")
```

This assumes your date starts in A1. basically its checking first if A1 is text or a number.  If its a number just format the number according to your set up.  If its text it strips off the last 4 number on the right for the year, the first two characters as the month and the middle two characters as the day.

This is not a complete solution and you will have to do a bit of work potentially to cover off the formatting.  what happens on say February 3rd for a date?  is it 02/03/2015 or is it 2/3/2015?  in the first case you dont need to do a thing.  But in the second case you are going to need to manipulate the way you pull the numbers out.  Hint you could use a combination of the FIND and MID function to figure out where the / are and then start pulling string.

Also read up on Datevalue and see if you can get it to work for you.

Personally I would not format your date as text because it limits what you can do with it later...actually case in point what you are currently dealing with.  You are far better to drop the text conversion to a format you like to converting the text to an excel date then changing how the cells display the information.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, just realized the date is invalid, there isn't a 31st for November. This fixed the issue.

[Ctrl `](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYjoM.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6jwb.png)

Really appreciate the brilliant insight.